# How can I iterate through individual rows in a list and use to input in form? Python

Tags: python, selenium

I have the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

#My list of [5,n] dimensional values 
ls = [ [3,10,19,20,25], [4,5,6,10,12]... [n] ]


#This is a website form that takes 5 values as input
element = driver.find_element_by_name("n1")
element1 = driver.find_element_by_name("n2")
element2 = driver.find_element_by_name("n3")
element3 = driver.find_element_by_name("n4")
element4 = driver.find_element_by_name("n5")

#After I find and store elements, I want to send 5 values from the list         
element.send_keys(str(ls[0]))
element1.send_keys(str(ls[1]))
element2.send_keys(str(ls[2]))
element3.send_keys(str(ls[3]))
element4.send_keys(str(ls[4]))

#Next I will submit form. Then loop again to retrieve next row of values 
#into form.
```

Currently I can only select one row from the list of values. I want to be able to create a for loop that allows me to select the next row of values after the program runs. I've found that maybe a nested loop may help, but not sure how to make it work.

**UPDATE:**

This is part of what I am trying to accomplish. I tried some of the code provided as feedback, but the loop is not working properly.

```
from selenium import webdriver


ls = [[1,5,10,16,19], [3,10,19,20,25], [1,2,11,16,29]]
for iter in range(3):
   driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')

   driver.get("http://lottery.com/site/winningNumberSearch?")

   select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('searchTypeIn'))
   select.select_by_visible_text("Number")
   select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('gameNameIn'))
   select.select_by_visible_text("Fantasy 5")

   elements = [driver.find_element_by_name("n" + str(i) + "In") for i in 
   range(1,6)]

   for values in ls:
       if len(elements) != len(values):
           #if theres an error, do something
            pass
       for element, value in zip(elements, values):
           element.send_keys(str(value))
           driver.find_element_by_id("submit").click()
   driver.quit()
```

**I got it to work like this**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("http://lottery.com/site/winningNumberSearch?")

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name("searchTypeIn"))
select.select_by_visible_text("Number")
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('gameNameIn'))
select.select_by_visible_text("Fantasy 5")

elements = [driver.find_element_by_name("n" + str(i) + "In") for i in 
range(1, 6)]



for k in ls:
    if len(elements) != len(k):
        pass
    for j, l in zip(elements, k):
        j.send_keys(str(l))
        #sleep(1)

    sleep(1)    
    driver.find_element_by_id("submit").click()
    sleep(1)
    driver.get("http://flalottery.com/site/winningNumberSearch?")
    sleep(1)
    select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name("searchTypeIn"))
    select.select_by_visible_text("Number")
    select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('gameNameIn'))
    select.select_by_visible_text("Fantasy 5")
    elements = [driver.find_element_by_name("n" + str(i) + "In") for i in 
    range(1, 6)]
```

Not perfect, but its working for me. Thanks much.

Comment: Loop is not working as I expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to address the elements as element[1], not element1:

```
elements = [driver.find_element_by_name("n" + str(i)) for i in range(1, 6)]

for values in ls:
    if len(elements) != len(values):
        # if you consider this an error, do something
        pass
    for element, value in zip(elements, values):
        element.send_keys(str(value))

    submit_form()
```

Comment: No I'm sorry - this isn't the place to debug code I can't run (and I don't even know the error, if any). I don't see anything wrong; I do see differences between both versions (time.sleep(1), the call to click() is in different positions, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

`ls` is a list of list. I guess following is what you need

```
element.send_keys(str(ls[0][0]))
element1.send_keys(str(ls[0][1]))
element2.send_keys(str(ls[0][2]))
element3.send_keys(str(ls[0][3]))
element4.send_keys(str(ls[0][4]))
```

Here's an example of a loop you can use :

```
for values in ls:
   for i in range(len(values)):
       print(values[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use loop

```
for values in ls:
    for i in range(1, len(values) + 1):
        element = driver.find_element_by_name("n{}".format(i))
        element.send_keys(str(values[i-1]))
```